# How to make GradientStopCollection Observable?

Tags: xaml, data-binding, collections, observablecollection, inotifypropertychanged

i have run into a problem where i want to show a list of gradient stops in a listbox. The problem is that putting the gradientstops in a collection of type ObservableCollection works, but using a GradientStopCollection does not.

When i Use GradientStopCollection, the items that are in the list before the window is initialized are shown, but when a button is pressed to add a third item, the UI is not updated. 
Calling OnPropertyChanged does not result in the UI being updated. I have made a small example to try to reproduce the problem.
So how can  get the window to correctly update even when i use a gradientstop collection?

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewModel vm = (DataContext as ViewModel);
            vm.Collection.Add(new GradientStop(Colors.Red, 0.5));
            //This line has no effect:
            vm.OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }
    }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace WpfApp1
    {
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public GradientStopCollection Collection
        {
            get
            {
                return collection;
            }
            set
            {
                collection = value;
            }
        }

        //Replacing GradientStopCollection
        // with ObservableCollection<GradientStop> makes it work
        GradientStopCollection collection;
        public ViewModel()
        {
            GradientStop a = new GradientStop(Colors.Green, 0);
            GradientStop b = new GradientStop(Colors.Yellow, 1.0);
            collection = new GradientStopCollection() { a, b } ;
            OnPropertyChanged("Collection");
        }

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public class Converter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (value is Color color)
                return new SolidColorBrush(color);
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targettype, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <local:Converter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>

            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type GradientStop}">
                <TextBlock
                    Width="50"
                    Background="{Binding Color, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}}"
                    Text="block"
                    />
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <ListBox
            x:Name="GradientListBox"
            Width="72"
            Height="92"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
        <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="169,264,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is any easy way around this problem.

You could create your own collection class, inheriting from GradientStopCollection and implementing the interface INotifyCollectionChanged, effectively making an ObservableGradientStopCollection.

You can probably find an implementation of INotifyCollectionChanged as an excmple.

It might be easier, just to keep two collections, although it seems like bad style.

Comment: Hi, I tried this, but GradientStopCollection is sealed. It does however have a Changed event. I could use this in code behind to force the listbox to update, but i want to go the viewmodel way. If i dont get this, i will just go back to using an observableCollection of GradientStop I guess.
AAAND. I just realized that sending notifications otherwise doesn't work, because they are not sent by the item the listbox is bound to *bonks head*